# Comparing speech input on Android with a word

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I made this to check if what people say contain "recherche" but it doest display the toast :

```
public void bn6(View view ){
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech to text");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        TextView speechText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.speechText);
        speechText.setText(matches.get(0).toString());
        String spec =  speechText.getText().toString();
        if (spec.toLowerCase().contains("Recherche")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "bravo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

so it changes the textview but it doesn't toast anything

Answer (score 0):

> spec.toLowerCase().contains("recherche")

Your text will always be false if you compare lower 'r' to Capital 'R'

Use "recherche" with lower case

Answer (score 0):

In this part :

```
spec.toLowerCase().contains("Recherche")
```

you convert **spec** to **lower case** but **Recherche** start with **R** that is an upper case! use this instead :

```
spec.toLowerCase().contains("recherche")
```

Comment: I did this but it still Toasting nothing

Comment: before your `if` toast the `spec ` and watch the resualt

Comment: if i say recherche it toast recherche and the textview is replace by recherche but the if does nothing :(

Comment: What do you mean by "the if does nothing"?

Comment: try  Nana Ghartey answer ! its a good practice to avoid future errors